# enclose a string where missing double quotes

Tags: shell, awk

I have an input file like below. The issue is that the file is pipe delimited and enclosed by double quotes, optionally. It is missed in the third field  at the end of the string and I could see that it happens whenever the length exceeds say 2.

```
"SER1828"|"ZXC"|"A1"|10002 
"SER1878"|"IOP"|"B1"|98989
"SER1930"|"QWE"|"A2"|10301 
"SER1930"|"QWE"|"Asdf2|10301 # 3rd field -> closing " missed out
```

The output should look like

```
"SER1828"|"ZXC"|"A1"|10002
"SER1878"|"IOP"|"B1"|98989 
"SER1930"|"QWE"|"A2"|10301 
"SER1930"|"QWE"|"Asdf2"|10301
```

I was trying with some awk commands but could not achieve it.

```
awk -F'|' -v q=\" '{$3=$3 q;}1' OFS=| temp  
awk -F'|' -v q=\" '{if (length($3) > 2) ($3=$3;}1)}' OFS='|'  temp
```

Comment: Within your double-quote encapsulated data, are there any pipes? Like... is there any data where there is a pipe that isn't a delimiter? If not, then just `gsub` the double quotes out, and then stick them back in again with your `print`.

Comment: No such non delimiter pipes, but the caveat is there are some fields which doesnt have the enclosed double quotes. See edits

Comment: Is it only ever the closing quote that is missing ? Also can there be pipes inside the quoted fields ?

Comment: If the quote can be missing at the start of a field too then you should include that in your sample or state it can only be missing at the end of the field. Ditto if it can occur in fields other than the third, especially start and/or end of the first and/or last fields. Include all the possibilities in your sample input, not just 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `awk` you can write,

```
awk -F'"?\\|' -vOFS='"|' '{print $1, $2, $3, $4}'
```

**Example**

```
awk -F'"?\\|' -vOFS='"|' '{print $1, $2, $3, $4}'  input
"SER1828"|"ZXC"|"A1"|10002
"SER1878"|"IOP"|"B1"|98989
"SER1930"|"QWE"|"A2"|10301
"SER1930"|"QWE"|"Asdf2"|10301
```

---

- **What it does?**
- `-F'"?\\|'` Sets the input field separator to either `"|` or `|`
- `-vOFS='"|'` Sets the output filed separator to `"|`. This is set always, that is even if the input field separator is `|` or `"|`

---

Or you can also write

<s>awk -F'"?\|' -vOFS='"|'  '1' input</s>

Here `1` is always evaluated to true, in which case it will print the entire line.

```
awk -F'"?\\|' -vOFS='"|'  '1' input
```

or

```
awk -F'"?\\|' -vOFS='"|'  '{$1=$1}1' input
```

See @Kent's comment.

---

**EDIT**

If you want to add the quoting only for the third filed based on the length, you can write something like

```
awk -F'|' -vOFS='|' '{print $1, $2, $3(length($3)>4 ? "\"" : ""), $4}'
```

Comment: Excellent on the first snippet. The second one doesnt work though.

Comment: @realspirituals My bad, removing it from the answer.

Comment: if you want to use the short form, you could try `$1=$1` or `{$1=$1}1`  instead of `1`, thus, the OFS will be applied.

Comment: @Kent Nice! I didn't know of that. Will update the answer. Thanks :)

Comment: keep in mind that `$1=$1` is short but with risk. If the `$1=0` or `$1=empty`, the line will be missing.

Comment: And the last thing I want to say is, Archlinux is truely sexy!  ;-)

Comment: @nu11p01n73R When I include another field which has unquoted numbers, this snippet is failing. If you see my example I tried, I had a logic of  checking for length and work only on that field, because I knew which field is having the problem. Could you please help?

Comment: @realspirituals I have added an edit. Hope this is what you are looking for

Comment: Excellent. Thanks mate

Answer (score 1):

this sed one-liner works for given example:

```
sed 's/\([^"]\)|"/\1"|"/' file  # this only works for the original example
```

This works for the original and current example:

```
sed 's/\([^"]\)|/\1"|/' file
```

Comment: Sorry Kent, just edited the post. There are fields without the double quotes. I need this only on a particular field rather than the whole file

Comment: @realspirituals I added some comments, the 2nd sed works both examples (old and updated)

Comment: can you please explain this? Is this substitution group?

Comment: @realspirituals yes it is regex match group and back reference.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{sub(/Asdf2/,"Asdf2\"")}1' file
"SER1828"|"ZXC"|"A1"|10002 
"SER1878"|"IOP"|"B1"|98989
"SER1930"|"QWE"|"A2"|10301 
"SER1930"|"QWE"|"Asdf2"|10301
```

Comment: Nopes, this doesnt work for the problem statement but works for the given dataset.